# Pimcore 5 Upload assets permissions

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

Is there a specific permission to enable users to upload only Assets?

The only way I have to enable Asset upload is to promote a user as Admin.
From the documentation: ([Users and Roles](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Administration_of_Pimcore/Users_and_Roles.html))

> •create: new child elements can be created (does not exist for assets)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could set the permission of uploading only assets by targetting assets path in workspaces of each user's role. There you have to specify by clicking on relevant checkboxes.